# audio book for subtractive synthesizing?

Tags: books, synthesis

Ok so im good at making sounds, but the only problem is, I dont know how to make the sounds I hear in my head. I was wondering if anyone knew of a good audio book out there (as sitting at my computer, reading off the screen hurts my eyes) that I could download and listen to about synthesizing? Or any tips on how to make the sounds I hear myself, but just cant seem to recreate?

Comment: Tried YouTube? I expect there are loads of tutorials like that out there. And keep experimenting until you better understand it ;)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about audio books, but this is a pretty "neat" book regarding the topic: http://www.synthesizer-cookbook.com/

Plenty of examples with precise "recipes" that you can copy and see what they're composed of. Working out those should give a better idea of how different styles of subtractive sounds can be made.

Also, this video series: [Intro To Synthesis - Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=atvtBE6t48M) (doesn't necessary need viewing to follow)

Btw: have you looked at adjusting your monitor's color balance and the background color of text documents to more eye-friendly settings, if those would help for the eye ache?